# ¿Por qué mi metodo onResponse no cumple su función?

Tags: php, java, android, android-studio, response

este es mi código:

```
public class RegistroActivity extends AppCompatActivity implements View.OnClickListener {

    TextView Nombre2;
    EditText N, Ap, E;
    Button S1;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_registro);

        Nombre2 = (TextView) findViewById (R.id.Nombre2);

        String f2 ="fonts/name.otf";
        Typeface name2 = Typeface.createFromAsset(getAssets(), f2);
        Nombre2.setTypeface(name2);

        N = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.N);
        Ap = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.AP);
        E = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.Edad);

        S1 = (Button) findViewById(R.id.S1);

      S1.setOnClickListener(this);

    }

    @Override
    public void onClick(View view) {

        final String Nombre = N.getText().toString();
        final String Apellido = Ap.getText().toString();
        final int Edad = Integer.parseInt(E.getText().toString());

        Response.Listener<String> respoListener = new Response.Listener<String>() {

            @Override
            public void onResponse(String response) {

                try {
                    JSONObject jsonResponse = new JSONObject(response);
                    boolean success=jsonResponse.getBoolean("Success");

                    if (success){
                        Intent intent = new Intent(RegistroActivity.this, Registro2.class);
                        RegistroActivity.this.startActivity(intent);
                    }else {
                        AlertDialog.Builder builder = new AlertDialog.Builder(RegistroActivity.this);
                        builder.setMessage("Error de registro")
                                .setNegativeButton("Retry",null)
                                .create().show();
                    }

                } catch (JSONException e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }

            }
        };

        RegisterRequest registerRequest =new RegisterRequest( Nombre, Apellido, Edad, respoListener);
        RequestQueue queue = Volley.newRequestQueue(RegistroActivity.this);
        queue.add(registerRequest);

    }
}
```

al ejecutarlo en el teléfono no responde el botón, no manda el registro ni accede al class que debería

Comment: Intenta poner algo más de debug con LogCat para saber si estas accediendo a tu método que es lo que parece, y en base a eso saber que parte de tu código se está saltando, (parece ser que hace falta algo que levante el respoListener).

Comment: al respoListener? que podria ser?

Comment: Primero pon los logs, para saber si estás entrando o no al evento, parece indicar que si estas entrando, por lo que desconozco el funcionamiento de las clases RegisterRequest, RequestQueue y Volley

Comment: Como sabes que no entra a onClick ? realizando debugging, comprobaste que no entra? @PedroLizarraga En realidad el problema puede ser tu petición.

Comment: Es porque uso la conexion php para registrar los datos en la base, me fui y cheque me base de datos ahorita y si registro los usuario muy tarde, pero no me accede a la siguiente activity que le marco al boton

Comment: @PedroLizarraga Entonces como comentaba si ejecuta el clic, el proceso que realiza dentro es el problema, si deseas que sea abra la activity asegura  lo que comento en mi respuesta, imprime que obtienes en "response".

Comment: Si pudiste resolver esto?
Tengo exactamente el mismo error :(

Answer (score 1, accepted):

En realidad si accede a tu método `onClick()` ya que esta definido y configurado correctamente el listener.

```
public void onClick(View view) {
   ...
   ...
```

El problema por el cual no abre el Activity `Registro2`, es porque tu respuesta (`response`) no esta recibiendo un objeto json que tenga el valor "Success"

```
JSONObject jsonResponse = new JSONObject(response);
boolean success=jsonResponse.getBoolean("Success");
```

`response` debe ser algo similar a :

```
 { "Success":"...", ..., ...};
```